# What is the large lowercase $n$ symbol in math?

Tags: notation

What is $\prod$ and how can I use it?
I have seen it used under numerous occasions and on the [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) graphing calculator keyboard-menu. I could not get it to work, and wanted some pointers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the $\prod$ symbol mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620187/what-does-the-prod-symbol-mean)

Comment: That is not an "n".  That is a capital $\pi$ and means product.  For example $\displaystyle \Pi_{j=1}^3 j  = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 6.$

Comment: @mjw : You are of course right about the origin of the symbol, but notice this difference: $$\begin{align} & \Pi_{i=1}^3 a_i \\ {} \\ & \prod_{i=1}^n a_i \end{align}$$ The first is coded as `\Pi` and the second as `\prod`, and the second is standard usage in mathematical notation.

Comment: Well yes, `\prod` is better than `\Pi` here.  Thanks for the prodding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by multiple users above, this is the uppercase version of $\pi$ in the greek alphabet, and it usually means "product".

In Desmos, you use it like this, similar to the summation sign ($\Sigma$):

$$ \prod_{i=a}^b {c} $$

where $a$ is the lower bound (bound included), $b$ is the upper bound (bound included), and $c$ is the component to take the product of.

An example:

$$ \prod_{i=1}^{10} {(i+2)}
= (1+2) \cdot(2+2) \cdot(3+2) \cdot(4+2) \cdot(5+2) \cdot(6+2) \cdot(7+2) \cdot(8+2) \cdot(9+2) \cdot(10+2)$$
$$ = 239500800 $$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice answer but the product evaluates to $ 239500800$. If you perform all the additions, you get $3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*11*12 = 12!/2$

Comment: Edited it in for you

Answer (score 3):

The Greek "S" is $\Sigma$ is typically used for sum. Analogously, The greek capital "P" is $\Pi$ and is typically used for product. We can use it to index some collection of numbers that we wish to multiply together. Say for example I wish to define $n! = n \cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)...\cdot 2\cdot 1$. I could write this as $\Pi_{k=1}^n k$ which says that we take every integer value $k$ between $1$ and $n$ and multiply them together.